# IIS 7.5 custom redirects

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

The original question has become redundant. The problem is IIS7.5 is over riding how aspdotnetstorefront handles the redirect to the error pages

The question is how can I make IIS7.5 handle redirects like IIS6 would

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some kind of url redirect..

Here is the post which may help you in that,

http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx

And the other one is

http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

Hope it helps.
Cheers.